# How to return vector formatted graphics from one thread to another?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, vector-graphics

I am designing a system in which there are multiple tasks which run in parallel. Each one of them gets some input, and should return graphical output in vector format.

The main WPF application should then draw the result of any of these tasks, upon user request. Currently I am using Canvas, Rectangle and other System.Windows.Shapes as my graphical vector format as output. When the task is completed, I take the Canvas children, and add them one-by-one to the GUI actual Canvas.

However, I've just discovered that UI elements cannot be created on any other thread than the main thread (so called Dispatcher thread).
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/wpf/thread/c4600372-342c-4ee4-b49c-d9abf967fc93 
Delegating the creation of the UI elements, (As suggested in the article above) to the main thread is not an option for me, since they should be shown whenever the user asks for the output, and not when the task is finished.

Actually I don't need to create UI elements in another thread, I just want a convenient method to create vector graphics and show them later in WPF application.

Does anyone has an idea what to do?

Comment: Can you serialize them on one thread, then deserialize them on the UI thread when needed?

Comment: Rachel, I cannot because I need to create the items on the Thread. It throws an exception immediately. Of course, I could create a **string** XML and deserialize in main thread, but that is too much hassle.

Comment: You have to do the work that *describes* what you wish to display, then create the resulting elements on the UI thread.  For example, instead of creating an actual S.W.S.Rectangle, you create a (for example) Rect with possibly more information (x,y, transforms, etc) and then generate the actual Rectangle with this information.

Comment: @Will, Can you explain why you removed the .NET4.0 C# WPF from the header of my question?

Comment: @Andrey: Tags that aren't organic to the title shouldn't be included.  We have a pretty good tag system.  There is no need to stack additional tags in the title.  If you head over to [meta] and search on the subject, you'll find lots of information about why we discourage this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another possible answer. One should use GeometryDrawing classes instead of Shapes when graphics are not drawn but rather defined, as in my case. It has the **Freeze** method, which allows passing it through different threads, because it is immutable.
Taken from Microsoft MSDN:

> The System.Windows.Shapes.Shape class has a Fill, Stroke, and other rendering properties that Geometry and its derived classes lack. The Shape class is a FrameworkElement and therefore participates in the layout system; its derived classes can be used as the content of any element that supports UIElement children.

The Geometry class, on the other hand, simply defines the geometry of a shape, and cannot render itself. Because of its simplicity, it has a wider range of uses.

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.aspx#inheritanceContinued)

Answer (score 1):

Capture `SynchronizationContext` of the UI ( main thread) before starting the parallel activities. And call (whenever you need) `Send` method on the captured `SynchronizationContext` reference in order to push the message into UI thread.
[MSDN on SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SynchronizationContext UISyncContext;
        YourTaskOutPut Myresult;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public StartProcessingVGraphics()
        {
            //Let say this method is been called from UI thread. i.e on a button click
            //capture the current synchronization context

            UISyncContext=TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext;

            //Start your VGraph processing using TPL in background and store result to Myresult (of type YourTaskOutPut)
            result= GetMeTaskResults();

        }

        public GetMeResultNow()
        {
            //Let's say this is is the method which user triggers at
            //some point in time ( with the assumption that we have Myresult in hand)

            if(UISyncContext!=null)
                UISyncContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(delegate{ PutItInUI }),null);

            //Use Send method - to send your request synchronously
            //Use Post method- to send your request asynchronously
        }
        void PutItInUI()
        {
            //this method help you to put your result in UI/controls
        }
```

Comment: I've found http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/SyncContextTutorial.aspx. Do you have better explanation?